# fire and smoke not being rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So i made a house for a schoolproject about fire safety for eldery people but when i render the animation no smoke is showing. i'm using cycles render for rendering and i've set a flow and domain. the rest of the objects or marked as collission. if needed i can upload the .blend

edit: here is the .blend fiel https://www.dropbox.com/s/izwpdj7wegb5hzo/brandend_uis.blend.zip?dl=0

Comment: A bit more detail about your setup would be useful. A screenshot would also be nice.

Comment: We NEED more detail to help you

Comment: Have you set up the smoke material on the domain?

Comment: no i haven't. will that help?

Comment: i have just tried it and it does not work